# How to add product sku to amasty xsearch search result preview?

Tags: magento2.3, amasty

I install amasty xsearch and want to add Product SKU to product template on search result preview - above product name.
[image]

Here is a template code(amasty/xsearch/view/frontend/template/product.phtml), where must product sku.
getProducts();
?>

```
<?php if (count($products)): ?>
    <div class="amsearch-products" data-amsearch-js="products">
        <p class="amasty-xsearch-block-header">
            <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($block->getTitle()))?>
        </p>
        <div class="amsearch-wrapper-content">
            <?php foreach ($products as $id => $product): ?>
                <div class="amsearch-item product-item" data-amsearch-js="product-item" data-search-block-type="product"
                     data-click-url="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getFullLink($product['url'])) ?>">
                    <div class="amsearch-autocomplete-image">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $product['img'] ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amsearch-autocomplete-information">
                        <div class="information-container">
                            <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                <a class="product-item-link"
                                   href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getFullLink($product['url'])) ?>"
                                   title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->stripTags($product['name'])); ?>">
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $product['name'] ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php if ($block->isShowDescription($product)):?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $product['description'] ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ($block->getReviews()): ?>
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $product['reviews'] ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="amsearch-wrapper-inner">
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $product['price'] ?>
                                    <?php if ($block->getAddToCart()) : ?>
                                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions"
                                             item-actions="1"
                                             data-amsearch-js="item-actions">
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($product['is_salable']): ?>
                                                    <form id="<?= 'amasty-xsearch-product-' . $escaper->escapeHtml($id); ?>"
                                                          data-role="tocart-form"
                                                          action="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($product['cart_post_params']['action']); ?>"
                                                          method="post" class="amasty-xsearch-form"
                                                    >
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="product"
                                                               value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($product['cart_post_params']['data']['product']); ?>">
                                                        <?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()): ?>
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="return_url"
                                                                   value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($product['cart_post_params']['data']['return_url']); ?>">
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                        <input type="hidden"
                                                               name="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->getUlrEncodedParam()); ?>"
                                                               value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($product['cart_post_params']['data'][$block->getUlrEncodedParam()]); ?>">
                                                        <input name="form_key"
                                                               type="hidden"
                                                               value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->getFormKey()) ?>"/>
                                                        <button type="submit"
                                                                title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                                            <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php if ($product['is_salable']) : ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available">
                                                            <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                            <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>

                                            <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary">
                                                <?php if ($block->isWishlistAllowed()) : ?>
                                                    <a href="#"
                                                       class="action towishlist"
                                                       title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                                       aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                                       data-post='<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($product['wishlist_post_params']); ?>'
                                                       data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                       role="button">
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>

                                                <a href="#"
                                                   class="action tocompare"
                                                   title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                                   aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                                   data-post='<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($product['compare_post_params']); ?>'
                                                   role="button">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ($block->getNumResults() > $block->getLimit()): ?>
            <div class="amsearch-more-results">
                <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getResultUrl()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('View All'))?>"
                    class="amsearch-link">
                    <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('View All')) ?>
                    <span> (<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->getNumResults()) ?>)</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <script>
        require([
            'jquery',
            'mage/mage',
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
        ], function ($) {
            'use strict';
            $('.amasty-xsearch-form').catalogAddToCart({});
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I try just add this code - after the line

```
<div class="product details product-item-details">
```

adding product sku:

```
<div> class="sku">
 <div class="label"><?php echo __('SKU-nbr.: '); ?> <?php echo $product->getSku(); ?> 
 </div>
</div>
```

but it's dont work.
Any idea?

updated.
product.php

```
namespace Amasty\Xsearch\Block\Search;

use Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductModel;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Product extends ListProduct
{
    const BLOCK_TYPE = 'product';
    const MEDIA_URL_PLACEHOLDER = '$$XSEARCH_MEDIA_URL$$';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_LIMIT = 'product/limit';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_TITLE = 'product/title';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_NAME_LENGTH = 'product/name_length';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_DESC_LENGTH = 'product/desc_length';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_REVIEWS = 'product/reviews';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_ADD_TO_CART = 'product/add_to_cart';
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_OUT_OF_STOCK_LAST = 'product/out_of_stock_last';

    const SMARTWAVE_PORTO_CODE = 'Smartwave/porto';

    const IMAGE_ID = 'amasty_xsearch_page_list';

    const PORTO_IMAGE_ID = 'amasty_xsearch_page_list_porto';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
     */
    private $string;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
     */
    private $formKey;

    /**
     * @var \Amasty\Xsearch\Helper\Data
     */
    private $xSearchHelper;

    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    private $redirector;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var array|null
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $mediaUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
     */
    private $stockHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    private $wishlistHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface
     */
    private $design;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Amasty\Xsearch\Helper\Data $xSearchHelper,
        RedirectInterface $redirector,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $design,
        \Magento\Framework\Url $urlBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->xSearchHelper = $xSearchHelper;
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->stockHelper = $stockHelper;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
        $this->design = $design;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->setData('cache_lifetime', AbstractSearch::DEFAULT_CACHE_LIFETIME);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $cacheKey = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
        return array_merge(
            [
                $this->getQuery()->getQueryText(),
                'group' => $this->xSearchHelper->getCustomerGroupId()
            ],
            $cacheKey
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [AbstractSearch::DEFAULT_CACHE_TAG, AbstractSearch::DEFAULT_CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getBlockType()];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_template = 'search/product.phtml';
        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return $this
     */
    public function prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($category)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockType()
    {
        return self::BLOCK_TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $ids
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIndexedIds(array $ids)
    {
        return $this->setData('indexed_ids', $ids);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            if (!$this->getIndexedIds()) {
                $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
            } else {
                $this->_productCollection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->collectionFactory->create())
                    ->addIdFilter($this->getIndexedIds())
                    ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                $this->stockHelper->addIsInStockFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function initializeProductCollection()
    {
        //Parent part without blocks and sorting initializing.
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            try {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $category = null;
            }

            if ($category) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }

        $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }

        //Custom part.
        $collection->clear();
        $collection->setPageSize($this->getLimit());
        $collection->setOrder('relevance');
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        if ($this->products === null) {
            $this->products = $this->getResults();

            if ($this->getAddToCart()) {
                $productModel = $this->productFactory->create();
                foreach ($this->products as &$product) {
                    $productModel->setData($product['product_data']);
                    $product['cart_post_params'] = $this->getAddToCartPostParams($productModel);
                    $product['compare_post_params'] = $this->getCompareProductsPostParams($productModel);
                    $product['wishlist_post_params'] = $this->getAddToWishlistParams($productModel);
                }
            }

            if ($this->getQuery() && $this->getNumResults() !== null) {
                $this->getQuery()->saveNumResults($this->getNumResults());
            }
        }

        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel $productModel
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompareProductsPostParams($productModel)
    {
        $currentComparePostParams = $this->_compareProduct->getPostDataParams($productModel);
        $currentUenc = $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl();
        $newUenc = $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl($this->redirector->getRefererUrl());

        return str_replace($currentUenc, $newUenc, $currentComparePostParams);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getResults()
    {
        $results = [];
        $imageId = $this->getImageId();
        foreach ($this->getLoadedProductCollection() as $product) {
            $data['img'] = $this->encodeMediaUrl(
                $this->getImage($product, $imageId)->toHtml()
            );
            $data['image_url'] = $this->getImage($product, $imageId)->getImageUrl();
            $data['url'] = $this->getRelativeLink($product->getProductUrl());
            $data['name'] = $this->getName($product);
            $data['description'] = $this->getDescription($product);
            $data['price'] = $this->getProductPrice($product);
            $data['min_price'] = $product->getData('min_price');
            $data['final_price'] = $product->getData('final_price');
            $data['is_salable'] = $product->isSaleable();
            $data['product_data'] = [
                'entity_id' => (string)$product->getId(),
                'request_path' => (string)$product->getRequestPath()
                ];
            $data['reviews'] = $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW);
            $data['rating_summary'] = $product->getData('rating_summary');
            $data['cart_post_params'] = $this->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
            $results[$product->getId()] = $data;
        }

        $this->setNumResults($this->getLoadedProductCollection()->getSize());
        return $results;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private function getImageId()
    {
        return $this->isPortoTheme() ? self::PORTO_IMAGE_ID : self::IMAGE_ID;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isPortoTheme()
    {
        return $this->design->getDesignTheme()->getCode() == self::SMARTWAVE_PORTO_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Encode media url on elasticsearch reindex process in order to correctly handle pub/index.php execution.
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @return string
     */
    private function encodeMediaUrl($html)
    {
        if ($this->getLimit() === 0) {
            $html = str_replace($this->getMediaUrl(), self::MEDIA_URL_PLACEHOLDER, $html);
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private function getMediaUrl()
    {
        if ($this->mediaUrl === null) {
            $this->mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        }

        return $this->mediaUrl;
    }

    public function getFormKey(): string
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLimit()
    {
        if ($this->getData('limit') === null) {
            $limit = (int)$this->xSearchHelper->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_LIMIT);
            $this->setData('limit', max(1, $limit));
        }

        return $this->getData('limit');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Search\Model\Query
     */
    public function getQuery()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_AMASTY_XSEARCH_QUERY);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getResultUrl()
    {
        $result = null;
        if ($this->getQuery()) {
            $result = $this->xSearchHelper->getResultUrl($this->getQuery()->getQueryText());
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $text
     * @return string
     */
    public function highlight($text)
    {
        if ($this->getQuery()) {
            $text = $this->xSearchHelper->highlight($text, $this->getQuery()->getQueryText());
        }

        return $text;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->xSearchHelper->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_TITLE);
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel $product
     * @return string
     */
    private function getName(ProductModel $product)
    {
        $nameLength = $this->getNameLength();
        $productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true);
        $text =
            $nameLength && $this->string->strlen($productNameStripped) > $nameLength ?
            $this->string->substr($productNameStripped, 0, $this->getNameLength()) . '...'
            : $productNameStripped;
        return $this->highlight($text);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    private function getNameLength()
    {
        return (int)$this->xSearchHelper->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_NAME_LENGTH);
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription(ProductModel $product)
    {
        $descLength = $this->getDescLength();
        $productDescStripped = $this->stripTags($product->getShortDescription(), null, true);

        $text =
            $this->string->strlen($productDescStripped) > $descLength ?
            $this->string->substr($productDescStripped, 0, $descLength) . '...'
            : $productDescStripped;

        return $this->highlight($text);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function getPriceRender()
    {
        return $this->_layout->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            '',
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductModel $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAddToCartPostParams(ProductModel $product)
    {
        $result = parent::getAddToCartPostParams($product);
        $result['data']['return_url'] =  $this->redirector->getRefererUrl();

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUlrEncodedParam()
    {
        return Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $product
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShowDescription(array $product)
    {
        return $this->string->strlen($product['description']) > 0
            && $this->getDescLength() > 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    private function getDescLength()
    {
        return (int)$this->xSearchHelper->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_DESC_LENGTH);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return (bool)$this->xSearchHelper->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_REVIEWS) == '1' ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getAddToCart()
    {
        return (bool)$this->xSearchHelper->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_ADD_TO_CART) == '1' ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $products
     * @return array
     */
    public function sortProducts($products)
    {
        $isShowLast = (bool)$this->xSearchHelper
            ->getModuleConfig(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_OUT_OF_STOCK_LAST);
        if ($isShowLast) {
            $outOfStockProducts = [];
            foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                if (!$product['is_salable']) {
                    $outOfStockProducts[] = $product;
                    unset($products[$key]);
                }
            }

            $products = array_merge($products, $outOfStockProducts);
        }

        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    private function getRelativeLink($url)
    {
        $baseUrl = $this->getBaseUrl();
        $baseUrlPosition = strpos($url, $baseUrl);
        if ($baseUrlPosition !== false) {
            return substr($url, strlen($baseUrl) - 1);
        }
        return preg_replace('#^[^/:]+://[^/]+#', '', $url);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullLink($url)
    {
        $url = $this->getRelativeLink($url);
        return rtrim($this->getBaseUrl(), '/') . $url;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isWishlistAllowed()
    {
        return $this->wishlistHelper->isAllow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found a solution.
maybe, not the best, but worked.
In product.phtml after

```
<div class="amsearch-wrapper-content">
            <?php foreach ($products as $id => $product): ?>
```

place this code:

```
<?php $prod_id = $product['entity_id'] ?>
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$prod = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prod_id);?>
```

and after

```
<div class="product details product-item-details">
```

this code:

```
<div class="sku">
    <?php echo __('SKU-nbr.: '); ?> <?= $prod->getSku();?>
</div>
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is right except you need to change the SKU value that you try to print. Please review the following:

```
<div> class="sku">
    <div class="label"><?php echo __('SKU-nbr.: '); ?> <?php echo $product['sku']; ?></div>
</div>
```

Looks like you are trying to get value from the product object, but as per your sample code of template, **$product is an array of product detail**.

Comment: Yes, i understand. Sku is missing in this array.(i edited my post).
 I can't find file where this array was created

Comment: Ok. Please check the block class defined in XML file located in the layout directory from where that .phtml template file is called. Once you would find the block class file, search for "getProducts()" function, if you would not find that function in that block class, then find in the parent class which was extended in that block class.

Comment: original post is updated. Product.php added. 
I try to add this line -$data['sku'] = $this->getSku($product); not working